# Terminology for time before a ticket is raised and time after a ticket is completed

Tags: timeline, cycle-time

In our team, we get tickets from other teams. Currently we are trying to work on reducing the time to complete a requirement. We have split the time into 4 slices:

1. Time when a requirement is identified but the ticket has not been raised because the customer was not sure about which team gets the ticket.
2. Lead Time
3. Cycle Time
4. Testing time

The image below shows the split:

[image: Ticket Lifecycle]

Is there some name for the Yellow portion of the timeline?

Comment: Did you try with NOT READY?
Best regards!

Comment: Why is it not part of Lead Time? Or, alternatively, why does it take a significant amount of time before the requirement is identified and the ticket entered?

Comment: Hi Thomas Owens, It is currently considered as part of the lead time. However, I am trying to differentiate these both to highlight the fact that there is considerable time spent in this phase and we need a better way of doing things. We will then need to spend time on determining the root cause across the different teams. So, yes. Those are valid questions which we are trying to answer.

Comment: MrScrumMaster, thanks for the suggestion. There is a parallel state called "NOT READY" where a ticket is filed with less information than is necessary for the team to handle the request. So, we cannot use this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use **Logging time**.

As defined in ITIL, this is the *Process to record and prioritize the Incident with appropriate diligence, in order to facilitate a swift and effective resolution.*

More info at https://wiki.en.it-processmaps.com/index.php/Incident_Management

As a side note, I'd suggest to use the whole nomenclature already defined by ITIL. It'll ensure there's a common language to be used across the board, based on a very sound and known standard.

Comment: Thanks for the term. That sounds like the right term for us. Appreciate the help.